# Parallel foreach in Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, parallel-processing, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm converting my build process to a Jenkinsfile and in the process I'd like to streamline a few things.  I have a number of shared modules and deployed modules.  The deployed modules all have a Dockerfile in them, something like this:

```
Parent 
|-shared1
|-shared2
|-Deploy1
| \-Dockerfile
|-shared3
|-Deploy2
| \-Dockerfile
|-Jenkinsfile
|-pom.xml
```

They all have pom.xml.  What I would like to do is build all the shared components then in parallel build and publish the shared modules.  The problems I'm having are

1. Get only the deployed modules
2. Execute on unknown number of sub modules in parallel.

After some frustrated deleting, all I have is

```
stage('Build Test') {
  dockerSupport.insideContainer('dockerRepository/docker-mvn-ci:0.1.0') {
    sh 'mvn clean install'
  }
}

stage('Publish') {
    sh "docker login -u '${env.DOCKER_USERNAME}' -p '${env.DOCKER_PASSWORD}' https://dockerrepository"
}
```

---- **UPDATE**

Had to move on but I made a lot of progress.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
node {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'creds', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME']]) {

    stage('Checkout') {
      checkout scm
      gitSupport.configureEnvGitCommit()
    }

    dockerSupport.insideContainer('dockerRepository/docker-mvn-ci:0.1.0') {
      stage('Build Shared') {
        sh 'mvn clean'
        sh 'mvn install'
      }

      stage('Docker Login') {
        sh "docker login -u '${env.DOCKER_USERNAME}' -p '${env.DOCKER_PASSWORD}' https://dockerrepository"
      }
    }

    stage('Parallel') {
      def subfolders = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ls -1d */').replace("/", "").trim().split("\n")
      echo "${subfolders}"
      def branches = [:]
      for (int i = 0; i < subfolders.length; i++) {
        def index = i
        def folder = subfolders[index]
        branches["${folder}"] = {
          echo "In folder ${folder}"
          sh "./publish.sh ${folder}"
        }
      }

      echo "Starting build"
      sh "ls -la"
      parallel branches
    }
  }//withCredentials
}//node
```

So in the `stage('Publish')` section it builds a map of all the folders to a lambda (sort of) then executes all of them in parallel.  There are still a few kinks to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
pipeline {
agent { label "master"}
stages {
    stage('1') {
        steps {
            script {
                def tests = [:]
                for (f in findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')) {
                    tests["${f}"] = {
                        node {
                            stage("${f}") {
                                echo '${f}'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                parallel tests
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

}